# TcpClient Connection

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient

I am writing an application to send/receive some data to and from a server. I need to make a connection before sending some data and need to keep it open so that user can send data continuously. The user can close the connection at any time by clicking on disconnect button. I created 2 buttons, one to connect and one to disconnect.
Code behind Disconnect button is as below:-

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tcpclnt.Connected)
        {
            tcpclnt.Client.Disconnect(false);
            stm.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Connected");
        }
    }
```

code behind connect button is as below:-

```
    public ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    public TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
    public NetworkStream stm;

    private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!tcpclnt.Connected)
        {                
            tcpclnt.Connect("XX.XX.XX.XX", 5500);
            MessageBox.Show("Connected to server");


            stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            string sysname = "000B0000" + SystemName.Text.ToString();
            byte[] sys1 = asen.GetBytes(sysname);
            sys1[0] = 0; sys1[1] = 0;
            sys1[2] = 0; sys1[3] = 0xB;
            sys1[4] = 0; sys1[5] = 0;
            sys1[6] = 0; sys1[7] = 0;
            try
            {
                stm.Write(sys1, 0, sys1.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Error in Sending data");
            }
            if (stm.DataAvailable)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] bb = new byte[600];
                    int k = 8;                        
                    k = stm.Read(bb, 0, bb.Length);
                    string value = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bb, 8, k - 8);
                    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show("Error in Reading data");
                }
            }                
         }
         else {
                MessageBox.Show("Already Connected");
        }
    }
```

Now, when I click on Disconnect button and again click on connect button, it's throwing an exception on tcpclient.connect line. I don't understand why or how can I solve it.

Comment: Can u mention what kind of exception u r facing ?

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on this topic, but I think a possible solution would be to gracefully close the connection using tcpclnt.Close(). If you don't do this or let the garbage collector do it ungracefully, then you can't reconnect (I think). Close the stream, then close the tcpclnt rather than disconnect.

```
tcpclnt.GetStream().Close();
tcpclnt.Close();
```

Also, don't use tcpclnt.Connected to check if there's a connection. Just simply Close it.

**EDIT**

The above doesn't work. I don't know how to reuse the socket. This is how I got it to work...

```
private void DisconnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tcpclnt.Close();
    tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
}
```

You mentioned that re-instantiating the object creates additional threads. This might be true as I'm unsure how to test for this. I opened up the windows resource monitor and watched the thread count for the app and it didn't show an additional thread opening each time.

Comment: that also not working....actually problem is tcpclnt.Connect is giving problem every time. I can do one thing that I can define "public TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient(); " everytime I try to connect, but seems that will create a lot of open threads....if user clicks on connect button 10 times, then it will create 10 open connections....(Not sure on this part, as I am new in this tech)..PLease suggest will that be a good way to do this.

Comment: Be careful closing streams and connections like that because they are closely bound to the socket so in the case of having to reuse the socket things might not be so graceful. For some reason the TCP library in C# is quite... winie. Just be careful :)

Answer (score 0):

Your .Disconnect() call needs to have true as the parameter to allow reuse. You currently are telling the socket to disallow reconnection. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnect.aspx) for the documentation.